# How can I calculate total user time on site across sessions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know the total amount of time any one of our users has spent on the site, across sessions.  Is there a way to find this stat in Google Analytics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related.  its about the usage of the Google analytics website

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track an individual customer through different sessions, it is not natively possible under Google Analytics, and there are quite a few traps you need to avoid to make sure to be complying with the conditions of use of the service. You can find more information [here](https://davidsimpson.me/2013/10/17/identifying-your-users-in-google-analytics-while-complying-with-section-7-of-the-terms-of-service/)

If you mean tracking the total duration of sessions, [Session Duration](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en) and Time on Page should give you what you want.

They basically measure the same thing, but can give you slightly different results depending on your implementation.